# Inno Setup: how to create a page with radio buttons and forms

Tags: deployment, installation, inno-setup

How can I put radio buttons and forms on the same Inno Setup page?

I currently have 3 fields:

[image]

I would like a radio button over the first field (Company / Name) and the third field (Customer Code).

Once a radio button is clicked, it disables the fields that aren't related to it (meaning making them a little grayish and unclickable).

So is there a way to put radio buttons and fields on the same page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inno Setup is flexible enough to allow what you need. But to have such a complicated GUI, you have to program this completely, you cannot do with simple utility functions like you are using atm probably (like `CreateInputQueryPage`).

You need to create:

- a new blank page using [`CreateCustomPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustompage)
- add radio buttons (`TRadioButton`)
- add input controls for all three forms
- handle `TRadioButton.OnClick` event and enable/disable respective forms based on selected button.

For a general introduction, see [Pascal Scripting: Using Custom Wizard Pages](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptpages).

---

Though for a faster start, you can actually start with `CreateInputQueryPage`, and only add your radio buttons and layout the text boxes correctly. To access individual edit boxes and their labels, use `TInputQueryWizardPage.Edits` and `TInputQueryWizardPage.PromptLabels`.

For some examples, see:

- [Select image file on custom layout page and and copy the file to installation folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37738681/850848)
- [Inno Setup: Combo box on TInputQueryWizardPage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45429989/850848)