# Select image file on custom layout page and and copy the file to installation folder

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

My goal is for the user to use this installer, insert your name, select your language and set custom parameters. That is done. But what I need is that the user selects an image to put it as avatar in the application, that is why the user to select an image and then copy the file to the application folder.

Something like this:

[image]

This is my code, if anyone can help would greatly appreciate it:

```pascal
[Code]
{ RedesignWizardFormBegin } // Don't remove this line!
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
procedure RedesignWizardForm;
begin
  with WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage do
  begin
    Left := ScaleX(350);
    Width := ScaleX(150);
    Height := ScaleY(57);
  end;

  with WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel do
  begin
    Width := ScaleX(309);
  end;

  with WizardForm.PageNameLabel do
  begin
    Width := ScaleX(293);
  end;

{ ReservationBegin }
  // This part is for you. Add your specialized code here.

{ ReservationEnd }
end;
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
{ RedesignWizardFormEnd } // Don't remove this line!

var
  NameEdit: TNewEdit;
  ParametresEdit: TNewEdit;
  LanguageCombo: TNewComboBox;
  LanguageNames: TStringList;

function ConvertLanguageName(const Value: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
  WideCharCode: Word;
begin
  Result := '';
  I := 1;
  while I <= Length(Value) do
  begin
    if Value[I] = '<' then
    begin
      WideCharCode := StrToInt('$' + Copy(Value, I + 1, 4));
      I := I + 6;
    end
    else
    begin
      WideCharCode := Ord(Value[I]);
      I := I + 1;
    end;
    SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + 1);
    Result[Length(Result)] := Chr(WideCharCode);
  end;
end;

function GetLanguageName(const Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := LanguageNames[LanguageCombo.ItemIndex];
end;

function GetPlayerName(const Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := NameEdit.Text;
end;

function GetParametres(const Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := ParametresEdit.Text;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  PlayerSettingsPage: TWizardPage;
  NameLabel: TLabel;
  LanguageLabel: TLabel;
  ParaLabel: TLabel;
  Info1Label: TLabel;
  Info2Label: TLabel;
  Info3Label: TLabel;
  Info4Label: TLabel;
  Info5Label: TLabel;
  Info6Label: TLabel;

  begin
  RedesignWizardForm;
  PlayerSettingsPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Ingrese Datos', 'Informacón del juego');

  NameLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  NameLabel.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  NameLabel.Left := 0;
  NameLabel.Top := 0;
  NameLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  NameLabel.Caption := 'Nombre';
  NameEdit := TNewEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  NameEdit.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  NameEdit.Left := 0;
  NameEdit.Top := NameLabel.Top + NameLabel.Height + 4;
  NameEdit.Width := 180;

  ParaLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  ParaLabel.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  ParaLabel.Left := 0;
  ParaLabel.Top := 100;
  ParaLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  ParaLabel.Caption := 'Parametros de Left 4 Dead 2';
  ParametresEdit := TNewEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  ParametresEdit.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  ParametresEdit.Left := 0;
  ParametresEdit.Top := ParaLabel.Top + ParaLabel.Height + 4;
  ParametresEdit.Width := 180;

  Info1Label := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  Info1Label.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  Info1Label.Left := 190;
  Info1Label.Top := 15;
  Info1Label.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  Info1Label.Caption := 'Introduzca su Nombre que se mostrara';

  Info2Label := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  Info2Label.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  Info2Label.Left := 190;
  Info2Label.Top := 30;
  Info2Label.Font.Style := [fsBold];  
  Info2Label.Caption := 'en el juego';

  Info3Label := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  Info3Label.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  Info3Label.Left := 190;
  Info3Label.Top := 65;
  Info3Label.Font.Style := [fsBold]; 
  Info3Label.Caption := 'Selecciona tu Idioma';


  Info4Label := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  Info4Label.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  Info4Label.Left := 190;
  Info4Label.Top := 120;
  Info4Label.Font.Style := [fsBold];  
  Info4Label.Caption := '-console: Muestra la consola';

  Info5Label := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  Info5Label.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  Info5Label.Left := 190;
  Info5Label.Top := 135;
  Info5Label.Font.Style := [fsBold]; 
  Info5Label.Caption := '-novid: Salta el intro del juego';

  Info6Label := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  Info6Label.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  Info6Label.Left := 190;
  Info6Label.Top := 150;
  Info6Label.Font.Style := [fsBold];  
  Info6Label.Caption := '-sw: Fuerza al juego en modo ventana';

  LanguageNames := TStringList.Create;
  #sub AddLanguageInternalNames
    #define GetLanguageInternalName(str S) \
      Local[0] = Copy(S, Pos("Name:", S) + Len("Name:")), \
      Local[1] = Copy(Local[0], Pos("""", Local[0]) + 1), \
      Copy(Local[1], 1, Pos("""", Local[1]) - 1)
    #emit '  LanguageNames.Add(''' + GetLanguageInternalName(LanguageList[LanguageIndex]) + ''');'
  #endsub
  #for {LanguageIndex = 0; LanguageIndex < LanguageCount; LanguageIndex++} AddLanguageInternalNames

  LanguageLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  LanguageLabel.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  LanguageLabel.Left := 0;
  LanguageLabel.Top := NameEdit.Top + NameEdit.Height + 8;
  LanguageLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  LanguageLabel.Caption := 'Lenguaje';
  LanguageCombo := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  LanguageCombo.Parent := PlayerSettingsPage.Surface;
  LanguageCombo.Left := 0;
  LanguageCombo.Top := LanguageLabel.Top + LanguageLabel.Height + 4;
  LanguageCombo.Width := NameEdit.Width;
  LanguageCombo.Style := csDropDownList;
  #sub AddLanguageDisplayNames
    #define GetLanguageDisplayName(str S) \
      ReadIni(S, "LangOptions", "LanguageName")
    #define GetLanguageFile(str S) \
      Local[0] = Copy(S, Pos("MessagesFile:", S) + Len("MessagesFile:")), \
      Local[1] = Copy(Local[0], Pos("""", Local[0]) + 1), \
      StringChange(Copy(Local[1], 1, Pos("""", Local[1]) - 1), "compiler:", CompilerPath)
    #expr LanguageName = GetLanguageDisplayName(GetLanguageFile(LanguageList[LanguageIndex]))
    #emit '  LanguageCombo.Items.Add(ConvertLanguageName(''' + LanguageName + '''));'
  #endsub
  #for {LanguageIndex = 0; LanguageIndex < LanguageCount; LanguageIndex++} AddLanguageDisplayNames
  LanguageCombo.ItemIndex := LanguageNames.IndexOf(ActiveLanguage);
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  LanguageNames.Free;
end;
```

My code currently produce this page:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest if to make use of the [`TInputFileWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputFileWizardPage) created using the [`CreateInputFilePage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputfilepage). There's nothing preventing you from adding your custom controls to the "input file" page. You just have to alter the layout of the automatically added "file input" controls.

You will also need to change type of the `PlayerSettingsPage` variable and make it global, so that you can access the values entered by the user outside of the `InitializeWizard` function.

```pascal
// global variables
var
  PlayerSettingsPage: TInputFileWizardPage;
  AvatarIndex: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Delta: Integer;
  ... // your other variables but not the PlayerSettingsPage
begin
  PlayerSettingsPage :=
    CreateInputFilePage(
      wpSelectComponents, 'Ingrese Datos', 'Informacon del juego', '');

  // Your existing code

  AvatarIndex :=
    PlayerSettingsPage.Add(
      'Avatar:', 'Image files|*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif|All files|*.*', '.jpg');
  Delta :=
    ParametresEdit.Top + ParametresEdit.Height + ScaleY(32) -
    PlayerSettingsPage.PromptLabels[AvatarIndex].Top;

  PlayerSettingsPage.PromptLabels[AvatarIndex].Top :=
    PlayerSettingsPage.PromptLabels[AvatarIndex].Top + Delta;
  PlayerSettingsPage.Edits[AvatarIndex].Top :=
    PlayerSettingsPage.Edits[AvatarIndex].Top + Delta;
  PlayerSettingsPage.Buttons[AvatarIndex].Top :=
    PlayerSettingsPage.Buttons[AvatarIndex].Top + Delta;
end;
```

[image]

Then install the selected avatar in the [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  AvatarSource: string;
  AvatarDest: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    AvatarSource := PlayerSettingsPage.Edits[AvatarIndex].Text;
    AvatarDest := ExpandConstant('{app}\' + ExtractFileName(AvatarSource));
    Log(Format('Installing avatar from "%s" to "%s"', [AvatarSource, AvatarDest]));
    if FileCopy(AvatarSource, AvatarDest, False) then
    begin
      Log('Avatar installer');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Error installing avatar');
    end;
  end;
end;
```